# Angular JS using $http() get a status 200 response , but data is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I am trying to connect a GET request to a cgi url, I am getting the below mentioned response which has 200 status but null data.

```
call{"data":"","status":"200",
"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],
"transformResponse":[null]",
"url":"http://121.158.1.255/app_status.cgi?wlan",
""application/json,text/plan,*/*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

Do I need to include any header data ? If I do need to add WhyI am getting the status as 200 which means "Success"

Comment: Nothing prevents the server from sending an empty response along with response code 200. I think the server is the problem here.

Comment: @BiAiB Thanks for your comments, Server problem means? Could you please explain little more then i can try based on the same.

Comment: It means the server (your cgi url) is sending an empty response. This doesn't look like an error related to your front. Do you have control over the server code ? check the logs, maybe the server application is throwing errors or warnings.

Comment: OK.I will check the same.